# how to solve a loop import

Tags: python, import

I have a module that keep tracks of all the usage log, (usage.py)

I then created another module for drawing charts, (chart.py)
I wanna keep track of people using my chart.py, thus, I import usage.py into my chart.

Everything seems cool up to this point.

Now, I wanna display the chart of the usage in usage.py, thus, I tried to import chart.py into usage.py.

Kaboom !
It gives me this error:-

ImportError: cannot import name chart.

Anyway to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create a third file: `chart_display.py`?

Comment: Circular dependencies are pretty bad... Never do that.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are usually solved by refactoring shared components into a third module, and each original one imports that new module.

Answer (score 3):

What you also can do is the following:

```
# File n°1, toto.py
from tata import tataClass

    class totoClass:
       def __init__(self,):
           # here I can use data from tataClass

# File n°2, tata.py
    def method_using_toto():
        from toto import totoClass
        # here I can use data from totoClass
```

You have therefore to be very carefull in the position on the includes