# Python 2/3 retofit issue with imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a package written in Python 2, and I am trying to retrofit to work with Python 3.  It's been painful to say the least.  I have an issue using the **future** absolute_import part of the code.

This works in Python 2 but not Python 3, so I'm hoping someone can point out my issue.

The package structure is:

```
fusion
  -> __init__.py
  agol
    -> featureservice.py
    -> layer.py
```

The fusion init is defined as:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import agol
```

The agol sub package is defined as:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import featureservice
from . import layer
```

The featureservice.py has this import, where the issue is:
    from . import layer
The layer.py has a similar import:
    from . import featureservice

They each can reference each other where the layer could be a child of feature service.  But I get this import issue, what is the proper way to import this module into each py file?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by " get this import issue"? Is it an exception? Can you paste the exception here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular relative imports do not work in Python 3.

Circular imports are considered a bad practice because you've tightly coupled both modules to each other. You may want to consider why you need to import `featureservice` into `layer` and `layer` into `featureservice`.

Maybe there are some functions in each that should be in yet another module that is depended upon by both? Or maybe instead of further splitting these modules, you should merge them together?

Related reading:

- [Circular imports in Python 2 and 3](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/40bf84d5870c41a77dc6)
- [Relative import problems in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030264/relative-import-problems-in-python-3)