# relative import does not work in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project structure like this...

```
app/
    main.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        boot.py
        server.py
        controllers/
            __init__.py
            home.py
```

The imports are...

```
# main.py
from app import server

# server.py
from . import boot

# boot.py
from . import controllers

# controllers/__init__.py
from . import home

# controllers/home.py
from .. import boot
```

Now all the imports are working **except the last one**. The error thrown is...

```
ImportError: cannot import name boot
```

What's the problem? (I am using Python 3.2)

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing relative imports?  They tend to be fragile and also harder to read when doing maintenance down the road.

Comment: I have tried everything -- nothing is working. Can you suggest something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are importing `boot` which is importing `controllers`, which is then asked to import `home`, and `home` then tries to import `boot`, but it wasn't done importing yet. Don't do this, you are creating a circular dependency here.

Also see [Circular import dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Comment: So how do I circumvent the circular imports? Because I really need to import `boot.py` into `home.py`

Comment: By organizing your code better; restructure until you do not need to load parent packages would help, for example.

Comment: You have to restructure your code.  99% of the time, if your code fits a naturally hierarchical pattern, and your higher level components have to import your lower level ones, you have a design flaw.