# Circular intra-referencing submodules

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Words

The structure is as follows: a module `test` contains two submodules `test.foo` and `test.bar`.

`test.foo` has a function `inc()` that uses `test.bar.bar()` so based on the python documentation `from . import bar` is the proper way to include that, and this works as expected.

`test.bar` however, also has a function `inc2` that uses `test.foo.foo`, but when `from . import foo` is used, both of these modules break.

What is the correct method for achieving this? I've found little in the python docs or searching.

## Code

**test/_*init*_.py**

```
#empty
```

**test/foo.py**

```
from . import bar

def foo():
    print("I do foo")

def inc():
    print(bar.bar())
```

**test/bar.py**

```
from . import foo

def bar():
    print("I do bar")

def inc2():
    print(foo.foo())
```

**Error 1**

```
>>> import test.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import bar
  File "test/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import foo
ImportError: cannot import name foo
```

**Error 2**

```
>>> import test.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import foo
  File "test/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import bar
ImportError: cannot import name bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to factor out code needed by both modules into a third module which is imported by both.  For instance, put the `foo` function into a third module.

There are many previous StackOverflow questions about this, e.g., [Circular import dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python) .  See also http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports .

Comment: or combine the modules into one