# How to handle cyclic imports in python?

Tags: python, import

I'm new to python and I have directory like this

```
dir
--a.py
--b.py
--__init__.py
```

`a.py` has

```
from b import B
class A:
    #class body
```

`b.py` has

```
from a import A
class B:
    #class body
```

But when I try to run `a.py` I get error like:

```
File "/b.py", line 1, in <module
ImportError: cannot import name B
```

how should I resolve this?

`__init__.py` is empty.

Comment: This has gotta be a duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python

Comment: See also [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/744373/222914)