# ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, flask

I have two files `app.py` and `mod_login.py`

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from mod_login import mod_login

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
)
```

mod_login.py

```
# coding: utf8

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, session, url_for, request
from functools import wraps
from app import app

mod_login = Blueprint('mod_login', __name__, template_folder='templates')
```

And python return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mod_login import mod_login
  File "mod_login.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mod_login import mod_login
ImportError: cannot import name mod_login
```

If I delete `from app import app`, code will be work, but how I can get access to `app.config`?

Comment: What if you just try `from mod_login import *` and `from app import *`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: Cannot import name X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks - that was a saver! I dont see a circular reference but was still getting the above error. Using `*` helped. I wonder whats the logic though.

Comment: @Sebastian I spoke too soon. doesnt help. When I try to use the class it doesnt find it and gives the import error. I know there is no circular import and have also tried deleting all *.pyc files. Dont know what is missing

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The problem is that you have a circular import:
in app.py

```
from mod_login import mod_login
```

in mod_login.py

```
from app import app
```

This is not permitted in Python. See [Circular import dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python) for more info. In short, the solution are

- either gather everything in one big file
- delay one of the import using local import

Comment: This is a good solution to move import into local scope. It doesn't require a lot of refactoring of the code and can be done really fast.

Comment: is there any other reason why this might happen? "cannot import name X"

Answer (score 29):

This can also happen if you've been working on your scripts and functions and have been moving them around (i.e. changed the location of the definition) which could have accidentally created a looping reference.

You may find that the situation is solved if you just reset the iPython kernal to clear any old assignments:

```
%reset
```

or menu->restart terminal

Comment: In my case, I refactored a single python script into different modules, leaving some old .py and .pyc files around, and stumbled on the "cannot import name" error. After a useless search of circular references, your answer put me on the right way - deleting old files did the trick. thanks

Comment: Wanted to point out that this was a lifesaver. I did not have a circular reference, and was thoroughly confused as to why this was happening.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using local imports, you may import the entire module instead of the particular object. Then, in your `app` module, call `mod_login.mod_login`

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import mod_login

# ...

do_stuff_with(mod_login.mod_login)
```

mod_login.py

```
from app import app

mod_login = something
```

Answer (score 0):

When this is in a python console if you update a module to be able to use it through the console does not help reset, you must use a

```
import importlib
```

and

```
importlib.reload (*module*)
```

likely to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python and just encountered this same error while trying to refactor my code. The cause of the error was a bit different in my case.

My code is written in a single file and I'm reorganizing it into modules. I got the error after grouping my code into modules and trying to run the flask server from `run.py`. I tried the solutions given here but didn’t work for me.

Then I noticed that I had 2 different `__pycache__` directories-one within my package(named `src` in the attached snippet) and the other outside it. When I deleted the `__pycache__` directory outside my package, the error cleared and I could run the flask server.

```
|- __pycache__/     #deleting this directory solved it for me
|-  src 
    |- __pycache__/
    |- __init__.py
    |- static/
    |- templates
    …
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my Django project I have multiple apps and backend scripts, modules, packages that use the name `utils.py` for their purposes. Initially, the problem seemed to be name collision among the python pakcages on name `utils.py`. The collision also affected only one package. Renaming to `package_utils.py` solved the problem.

However, the root cause was a missing `__init__.py` file in one of the Django apps which also used a `utils.py`. Adding the missing file solved the problem w/o renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Probably as i guess, you didnt remove the comment section in the views.py folder, right under the first defualt django code, which is " from django.shortcuts import render "  ,under that you will find a comment just delete it and it will work fine.

that is the defualt comment made by the django app
" # Create your views here. " ,delete it because it might interfer in the app doing the functions as it is in the second line, after that you can use it, after the app runs correctly, after identifying the path

Answer (score 0):

In mycase, the imported module name collided with a local variable of the same name

```
# imported module 
from expiry_type import get_expiry_type

# local variable with the same name as the imported module name
expiry_type
```