# Python: cannot import name hmm

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I cant import hmm module from sklearn.

```
from sklearn import hmm
```

I get error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name hmm
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845366/importerror-cannot-import-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Hidden Markov Models site here](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/modules/hmm.html), the `sklearn.hmm` module has been deprecated and is scheduled for removal in the `0.17`. Confirm that your `scikit-learn` is at least version `0.16.1` because from `0.17` you won't have `sklearn.hmm`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you found a solution to your problem.

You can install and implement your HMM using [hmmlearn](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn).

It can be installed easily with a `pip install hmmlearn`.

To quote **Scikit-learn**,

> Warning The sklearn.hmm module has now been deprecated due to it no
>   longer matching the scope and the API of the project. It is scheduled
>   for removal in the 0.17 release of the project. This module has been
>   moved to a seperate repository: https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn

Comment: Hi @Pragyaditya and @ishmaelMakitla I am facing the same error and I did try `pip install hmmlearn ` but i am getting the same error - `ImportError: No module named hmm`. I even updated all the required modules, did you try anything else apart from this?

Comment: @AnkP which version of Python are you on?