# how to import the importer from an imported module

Tags: python, import, python-3.3

What I have is a module `data.py` that imports another module `element.py`. `data.py` needs the "element" class stored in `element.py` while the "element" class in `element.py` is a subclass of a template "element" class in `data.py`. and `data.py` is run first.

so:

**data.py**

```
import element.py

class templateElement(object):
    # all the class stuff here

class templateOtherObject(object):
    # needs element.py's custom element object methods and data
```

**element.py**

```
import data.py

class element(data.templateElement):
     # class stuff here
```

So how do I get it to where they can both get the information from each other while not having the template methods each designated to their own file. or would they have to be?

How could I set up a template file while still being able to use the custom classes in a different template class on the template file?

Comment: You should avoid circular imports. Move `templateElement` out to a different module and import it from both `data` and `element`.

Comment: Note that you'd import `element`, *not* `element.py`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular import dependency in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**data.py**:

```
class templateElement(object):
    # all the class stuff here

def somefunction():
    from element import element
    # needs element.py's element object
```

Meaning, just wait until you have to use it. That way loading data.py would not result in a circular importing.

Comment: so you're saying to just import the necessary part of the element.py file?

Comment: also, how could I do that dynamically because the way I am importing the element.py file is through a package dynamically and loading it via a string. the custom element class has the same name though.

Comment: `exec("from element import element")`? Or did I not understand your problem

Comment: no, I see what you're saying and I would use it if I knew how to do `from "element" import "element"` with those being strings, so that it can adapt to a dynamic number of custom element types, it's that I don't have just that one.

Comment: so yeah, you did give the correct answer, now I only need to adapt it slightly further. Thank you.

Comment: also, how would you tell element.py what "data" was for the data.templateElement, because it's not letting it run at import.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you mean. `import data` doesn't work for you from `element.py` ?

Comment: it doesn't work because it's running it from `data.py` in `element.py` and then trying to import back to `data.py`, which then is loading all of it and trying to run `import element.py` again, not finding it because it's then doing circular importing.