# Cannot Import From a Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class and function. When I try to run through it I am getting:

`ImportError: cannot import name Requests`

Here's my code:

```
from tests.global_functions.util_helper import util_get_random_customer_individual
from tests.global_functions.util_helper import util_get_random_customer_company
from requests import Requests
import random


class Customer():
    def __init__(self):
        request = Requests()
        customer = None
        if request.request_type == 'individual':
            customer = util_get_random_customer_individual()
        elif request.request_type == 'company':
            customer = util_get_random_customer_company()
        else:
            print 'What the hell should I do???? HELP!?!?!?!'
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/e003048/QA/trunk/automation/selenium/src/webservices/add_customers/webservice_requests.py", line 2, in <module>
    import webservices.system_environment.responses
  File "C:\Users\e003048\QA\trunk\automation\selenium\src\webservices\system_environment\responses.py", line 2, in <module>
    import connector
  File "C:\Users\e003048\QA\trunk\automation\selenium\src\webservices\system_environment\connector.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\e003048\QA\trunk\automation\selenium\src\webservices\system_environment\requests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from customer import Customer
  File "C:\Users\e003048\QA\trunk\automation\selenium\src\webservices\system_environment\customer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import Requests
ImportError: cannot import name Requests
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here or why I would be getting this error. I am using PyCharm and there is nothing indicating that anything is wrong in the import statement.

Comment: Provided you don't have different PYTHONPATHs that are interfering, this is probably a name conflict, though possibly also a circular import problem.  The call stack would seem to support this.  Do you have any of your own packages or modules named "requests"?

Comment: @SilasRay Yes, I have a `requests` module with a `Requests` class, which is what I am trying to import

Comment: i would recommend  trying `from request import *` though i am not sure if this is recommended

Comment: Oh, you aren't using the `requests` library then?  In any case, it looks like your `requests` module is attempting to import the `customer` module, and the `customer` module is attempting to then import the `requests` module.  This is a circular import.  `Requests` doesn't exist within the `requests` namespace yet, because the module hasn't been fully loaded before `customer` attempts to load it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular import dependency in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Comment: @KapelNick `import *` is never recommended.  And besides, it won't help in a circular import problem anyway, as at the time of import, the object in question does not exist to be imported in the first place.

Comment: @SilasRay yeah i thought so too, its not advisable to import namespace as a whole, but sometimes it might be a legit error deducting practice.

Comment: Given your other questions on SO about this same batch of code, I think you need a major refactor.  It looks like you are basically using the `Requests` class like a glorified dictionary, while you are stuffing what should be methods on `Requests`, or subclasses thereof, in to the `util_helper` module.  There appear to be fundamental structural problems with your code; addressing the narrow problem here with a hacky patch is not really going to fix your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have circular imports. `requests` imports `customer`, and `customer` imports `requests`.

Circular imports are actually allowed in Python, but they don't work well if you're attempting to do named imports (ie `from foo import Foo` rather than `import foo`). Python is trying to import `requests`, but to do that it needs to import `customer`. So part way through importing `requests` it starts importing `customer`. Then `customer` says it wants to look at the thing named `Request` in `requests`, but `requests` isn't finished loading so that name doesn't exist yet.

There are a few possible fixes:

1. The simplest may be for you to just switch to non-named imports. So then you'll have to say `requests.Request` instead of `Request` in the `customer` module.
2. A better option would be to try to eliminate the circular dependency. In general, circular dependencies are an indication that things are too tightly coupled. Either pull the circularity out into a third module, or merge the two modules.
3. A third option, but this is generally considered to be poor style, is to move the import of `customer` inside `requests` *below* the definition of the `Request` class. **Again, this is poor style, and I do not recommend it. I mention it here only for the sake of completeness, but if you do this you will almost certainly regret it later.**

Comment: Too tightly coupled, or just poorly designed/organized.