# Python modules importing each other

Tags: python, import, module

I have 2 modules importing each other, I try to nick a global variable from one of them into the other:

package1.module_1:

```
import package1.module_2 as module_2

SOME_VARIABLE = 5
```

package1.module_2:

```
import package1.module_1 as module_1

SOME_VARIABLE = module_1.SOME_VARIABLE
```

It gives the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module_2'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  don't use `as`.

instead of:

```
import package1.module_2 as module_2
```

use:

```
import package1.module_2
```

Comment: It works. But you should restructure your code instead if such changes may break it.

Answer (score 0):

the right syntax is

```
from package1 import module_1
```

and

```
from package1 import module_2
```

but will led to [circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Comment: `from package1 import module_1` is different from `import package1.module_1` The latter might work where the former fails due to circular imports