# Access a resource from parent file

Tags: python

```
# models/__init__.py

from shared.cache import Cache

class modelA():
    pass
class modelB():
    pass
class modelC():
    pass

# shared/cache.py

class Cache:
    def methodA():
        modelA.SomeStaticMethod()
```

Basically what I need is to access `modelA` from inside the `Cache` class.
If I try to import the models from cache.py, I get an error due to a circular reference error.

I know it seems a little bit weird but it's a very specific issue.
Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: It's sad how badly screwed up imports are in python. I often run into this problem myself, and have found at least 3 different stupid workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually restructure your files so that there is no circular reference error.

Simply answering your question, and usually seen as a workaround, you can import `Cache` on demand, only within the functions of `models/__init__.py` that make use of it. This may not be possible in this case, especially if `Cache` is used as a decorator at the module level.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python) question.