# how to clean up a Python package import statements

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, cyclic-dependency

So I decided to clean up my package, which has many modules. To that end I commented every single module import statement, and then when running the code I was just loading what I needed. However, this quickly became a nightmare where I find myself trying to solve for cyclic imports, and I have absolutely no idea on how I can solve this. What's the most straightforward manner of cleaning up a package? I don't think I'll get anywhere this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular import dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Comment: Not the same package, so that answer doesn't help.

Comment: Use flake8 it will indicate unused modules. Only remove those.

Comment: @Anthon the thing is that I moved files from the file directory, so my code doesn't run any longer... and as I understand, I should use flake8 with a functioning code, shouldn't I?

Comment: You'll have more false warnings if it doesn't run, but you'll get those when running the code as well if imports are no longer correct because of the moving around.

Comment: @Anthon do you have a link to a tutorial or something where I can learn how to do what you suggest?

Comment: http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/