# Flask ImportError: cannot import name ''

Tags: python, flask, import

This is my application tree, since this application is relatively big, I am using blueprints divisional structure to structure it.

```
RPOSS
├───.idea
├───app
│   ├───customer_panel
│   │   ├───static
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───owner_panel
│   │   ├───static
│   │   │   └───js
│   │   │       └───lib
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───progressive_panel
│   │   ├───static
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───Include
├───instance
│   └───__pycache__
├───Lib
├───Scripts
└───__pycache__
```

`RPOSS/app/run.py`:

```
from app import app
app.run()
```

`RPOSS/app/__init__.py`:

```
from app.views import Rmod
from app.customer_panel.views import Cmod
from app.owner_panel.views import Omod
from app.progressive_panel.views import Smod
from instance.config import engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


app = Flask(__name__,
        static_folder='./static',
        instance_relative_config=True,
        instance_path=r"C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\instance")
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db_session = Session()
Bootstrap(app)

app.register_blueprint(Cmod)
app.register_blueprint(Rmod, url_prefix="/RPOSS")
app.register_blueprint(Omod, url_prefix="/RPOSS/owner_panel")
app.register_blueprint(Smod, url_prefix="/RPOSS/progressive_panel")
```

`RPOSS/app/views.py`:

```
from flask import ...
from app.forms import ...
from app.models import ClassName


Rmod = Blueprint('RPOSS', __name__,
             template_folder='templates',
             static_folder='static')
```

`RPOSS/app/models.py`:

```
from app import bcrypt
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import ... 


Base = declarative_base()


class ClassName(Base):
    # I am using bcrypt here to hash values
    ...
```

Note: I ran the model and the database was created and everything was working fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Orbit/RPOSS/app/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import bcrypt
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\app\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app.views import Rmod
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\app\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.models import Employee
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\app\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import bcrypt
ImportError: cannot import name 'bcrypt'
```

Can someone help me figuring out what happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular import dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Comment: See also [larger applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) from the Flask docs, which explains this circular import problem.

Comment: You have a blueprint registration for  `Cmod` that is not imported anywhere, but `app.register_blueprint(Cmod)` is there.

Comment: i will definitely go and check them , thank you Phydeaux and sytech .

Comment: @MartijnPieters on it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import.

`app.models` tries to import `app` to resolve the name `bcrypt`:

```
  File "C:/Users/Orbit/RPOSS/app/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import bcrypt
```

The `app/__init__.py` file first imports another module however, `app.views`:

```
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\app\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app.views import Rmod
```

This module wants to import from `app.models`:

```
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\app\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.models import Employee
```

This is the file you started with, but you probably ran it as a script so was imported by Python as `__main__`, meaning Python will import it *again* under the `app.model` name.

But now you have a problem, because it imports `app` again:

```
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\RPOSS\app\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import bcrypt
```

At this point, `app` has already been created, but has not yet completed importing. The name `bcrypt` has not yet been assigned to.

You need to move the name `bcrypt` to a line before you import `app.model`. Move the line `from app.views import Rmod` to **below** the `bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)` line, or use a separate function to import your blueprints later on.

I prefer using an [*Application Factory*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) to set up the app and blueprints. Alter your `__init__` method to import blueprints in the factory function.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you so so much @martijn-pieters , wish you all the best really