# Django models how to fix circular import error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import, importerror

I read about a solution for the error (write `import` instead of `from ...`) but it doesn't work I think because I have a complex folder structure.

Directory structure
[image]

#### quiz/models.py

```py
import apps.courses.models as courses_models


class Quiz(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(courses_models.Lesson, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  # COURSE APP MODEL IMPORTED
```

#### courses/models.py

```py
import apps.quiz.models as quiz_models


class Lesson(models.Model):
   ...

class UserCompletedMaterial(models.Model):
   ...
   lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
   quiz = models.ForeignKey(quiz_models.Quiz)  # QUIZ APP MODEL IMPORTED
```

---

How you can see I just can't keep it together or something else..
Because I think the `UserCompletedMaterial` model is a part of `courses` app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both models refer to each other, and this thus means that in order to interpret the former, we need the latter and vice versa.

Django however has a solution to this: you can not only pass a reference to the `class` as *target* model for a `ForeignKey` (or another relation like a `OneToOneField` or a `ManyToManyField`), but also through a *string*.

In case the model is in the same application, you can use a string `'ModelName'`, in case the model is defined in another *installed* app, you can work with `'app_name.ModelName'`. In this case, we thus can remove the circular import with:

```
# do not import the `courses.models

class Quiz(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(
        'courses.Lesson',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    # …
```