# How to call a function inside main function from library in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I've a second.py as library which is called by main.py. I want to call a function inside main.py when a loop in second.py trigger. Here is the basic structure of my code. (The whole code is much bigger, I just simplified it, so structure should not be changed)

```
# main.py
import second


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.second_functions = second
        self.data_from_second = None

    def func1(self):
        # Initiate something in second
        print(self.second_functions.SecondClass.test1(self))

    def func2(self, data):
        # Do something with data
        self.data_from_second = data
        print(f"{data}")


Main().func1()
```

```
# second.py
import time


class SomeHandler:
    pass


class SecondClass(SomeHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "Something"

    def test1(self):
        # do some stuff
        self.something = "Initiated"
        print("Second Class Initiated")

        while 1:
            # !!! from this point I want to trigger func2() in running main.py
            print("Trigger func2('some data')")
            # Main.func2("DATA") #When I try someting like this, it returns "NameError: name 'Main' is not defined" which is normal.
            time.sleep(3)
```

second.py is actualy a socket server. When client sends something, I need to pass that info to main.py. Currently main.py call a function inside second.py in interval to get datas which is not right way I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import main` (or rather `from main import Main`) in `second.py`, because currently `second.py` doesn't know what is '`Main`'.

However it is not possible to `import main` in this case, due to a circular dependency issue, for which there are answers here: [Circular import dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python)

Also be aware that you can't call `Main.func2("data")`, because `func2` is not a `@classmethod`, main needs to be instantiated first with brackets `Main()` or use the `@classmethod` decorator in `Main.func2()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the reference to `func2` to the `SecondClass.test1()` call:

```
# main.py
import second


class Main:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.second_functions = second
        self.data_from_second = None
enter code here
    def func1(self):
        # Initiate something in second
        inst = second_functions.SecondClass()
        print(inst.test1(callback=self.func2))

    def func2(self, data):
        # Do something with data
        self.data_from_second = data
        print(f"{data}")


Main().func1()
```

Notice how we can now call the fn and pass it data. This is a callback pattern.

```
# second.py
import time


class SomeHandler:
    pass


class SecondClass(SomeHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "Something"

    def test1(self, callback):
        # do some stuff
        self.something = "Initiated"
        print("Second Class Initiated")

        while 1:
            data = 123
            callback(data)
            time.sleep(3)
```