# Python how to use function in imported file defined in importing file?

Tags: python, import, python-import

Sometimes, I see examples like this, but I don't understand how do they work. Imported module uses function without any places in which this function is set to use. Please can someone explain me how to use them.

Example:

```
from some_package import *

def some_func():
    # do_something
    pass
    
imported_func()
```

And then imported_func somehow defines some_func and uses it. How is this implemented?
When I tried to call some_func from module.py I received an error. Again: idea is to use function from imported file which was defined in importing file. I couldn't find answer in google.

I tried:

```
from f.module import *
obj = cls()

def some_func():
    for _ in range(100):
        print("smth")
        
obj.imported_func()
```

Code in main.py

```
class cls:
    @staticmethod
    def imported_func():
        some_func()
```

Code in module.py

I have main.py and folder f in one directory. In folder f I have module.py

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking. What error do you get? Which files?  It looks like you have imported `imported_func` from `some_package` (e.g. from the file `some_package.py`, though it could be from `some_package/__init__.py`). "imported_func somehow defines some_func and uses it" that's not what the code shows.  "I tried to call some_func from module.py I received an error" ... is the code above in `module.py`?

Comment: Thanks, I extended question

Comment: For `f` to behave as a package you need to have an empty file `f/__init__.py`.  But what you are trying to do will have a "circular import" problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556387/circular-import-dependency-in-python) i.e. `f/module.py` needs to import `some_func` from `main.py` and `main.py` needs to import `cls` from `f/module.py`

Comment: `imported_func` is a staticmethod so you don't need to instantiate the cls here `obj = cls()`, you can just do `cls.imported_func()`

Comment: and `cls` is a bad name for a class - convention in Python is to use CapitalCase names... additionally if you were to make a method with `@classmethod` then the convention is for the first arg to the method to be named `cls` ...so that would be very confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is at first `import __main__` then call `__main__.some_func()`, but remember, it's not a good practice because at least you are reserving name, what can become common reason for errors.